# Install Python 2.5 on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: installation, python

I need to install Python 2.5 for compatibility with Google App engine. 
I tried the .msi install, it appeared to run, but never created the directory.

From this page: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5/ 
I don't understand why they advertise a Itanium and AMD version, but not a regular Windows 64-bit version - or am I missing it?

Do I really need to download "python-2.5.tgz"?

Update: I ran the AMD64 version, and same problem.  I tried to install to c:\Python25, and the directory does not exist after the install.  A voice in my head said "Run as Admin", but that option seems to be available on .exe's but not .msi's.  After the supposed install, I can see Python in Control Panel - Programs and Features, and can unintsall it.

Update 2 note: I added this second issue as a new question here: 
[Python install puts all files/libs in c: root directory (Windows 7 64-bit)](https://superuser.com/questions/84861/python-install-puts-all-files-libs-in-c-root-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

amd64 is what you're after. AMD were the first to implement the 64-bit extension of the x86 instruction set, then others followed and created their own implementation. The name AMD64 was for marketing, and it sort of stuck. If you're looking for 64-bit software, it may be labeled as x64, 64-bit, x86-64, or amd64.

As per wikipedia:

> The term x86-64 is the original naming
>   of a 64-bit extension to the x86
>   instruction set specified by Advanced
>   Micro Devices (AMD) and implemented by
>   AMD, Intel, VIA, and others.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.  But please see update to my question above - still not working.

Comment: I have it running on 64-bit Windows 7 myself so this is news to me. Are you running a full version of 7? You could try extracting the msi's contents using Universal Extractor: http://legroom.net/software/uniextract then installing components separately. Maybe ActiveState's ActivePython will work better for you, you can grab version 2.5.4.4 here: http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePython/windows/2.5/ActivePython-2.5.4.4-win64-x64-nopywin32.msi

Comment: I would definitely go with the ActiveState distribution. However, be aware that the x64 version of ActivePython doesn't include/support the PyWin32 extensions. If you need them, you'll need the x86 version, which runs fine on W7x64. Also note for anybody interested, you'll need the 2.6.x release of ActivePython if you want to use their Python package manager. It isn't included with earlier versions.