# Python install puts all files/libs in c: root directory (Windows 7 64-bit)

Tags: installation, python

Python .msi installer (On Windows 7 64-bit) is installing all files in the root of the c: drive, instead of in c:\Python25 (where I told it).

I have tried creating the c:\Python25 before running the installer, which was no help.

The version of the installer I'm running is python-2.5.amd64.msi (for compatibility with Google App Engine).

Thanks,

Neal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you specify `C:\Python25` as the install directory in the GUI installer? It should respect that setting. If not, you can specify a target install directory from the command line like this:

```
msiexec /i python-2.5.amd64.msi TARGETDIR=c:\python25
```

Ensure you are in the directory containing the msi when you run the command, and that command prompt has been run as administrator.

Comment: Needs to be "Run as Admin" when you open command prompt.

Comment: Forgot about that tidbit, answer updated. Thanks!

Comment: So why doesn't it just fail instead of creating directories in the wrong place?  I hate having to clean them up.

Comment: Bad installer design I suppose. Revo Uninstaller should take care of it for you: http://www.revouninstaller.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's sad my memory is so bad.  I had the same problem back in July on on Windows Vista 32-bt machine.

http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=13651&p=63528&hilit=root+dir#p63528

The solution was to open command prompt with "RUN AS ADMIN", then do this command:
msiexec /i python-2.5.4.msi

I'm not sure why more people aren't having the same problem.

Neal

Comment: It happens to the best of us :P